# What's the proper syntax to keying into Netlify env vars?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, gatsby, netlify

My Gatsby app hosted on Netlify is throwing an error concerning my Firebase config.

What's the proper syntax for keying my app into Firebase via Netlify & Gatsby ?

My config is at the top of my src/components/Firebase/firebase.js:

```
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID

};
```

Locally, at the top of my gatsby-config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
 })
```

On Github, I'm omitting the require statement in my gatsby-config.js because Netlify has a copy.

Yet, I'm getting is an error both local and Netlify:

```
Uncaught (in promise) code: "auth/invalid-api-key"
message: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it 
correctly.
```

Yep, I checked, my env vars are fine..

I thought this would be straight forward. My app ought to have access to the config data based on the fact that Netlify has a copy.

Playing around I saw yy app works locally and on Netlify if I pass the sensitive firebase config directly via firebase.js. But, Obviously that's a no-no.

Anyone else experience similar results in getting a similar setup to work?

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/7381

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who use create-react-app, added prefix REACT_APP_ to your env vars, added them to the Netlify build env vars in the settings and have deployed onto Netlify site but still see the

```
Uncaught (in promise) code: "auth/invalid-api-key", message: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.
```

My case was resolved simply by re-deploy the app again on Netlify.

Comment: Re-deploy works for me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> OS Env Vars which are prefixed with GATSBY_ will become available in browser JavaScript.

Gatsby requires you to use the following syntax for accessing [client side environment vars](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#client-side-javascript). Change them in your code and in the Netlify app console.

```js
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.GATSBY_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.GATSBY_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.GATSBY_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.GATSBY_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.GATSBY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID

};
```

***Note:*** [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/2597114)

Comment: Thanks guys! That worked. I needed the require("dotenv").. in gatsby-config.js, and in my .env I used GATSBY_ prefix.